# Trying to post xml content to wsdl

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have been trying to post some XML content to a WSDL URL. When I try to post the content I receive the following error **(SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'core_submission' property)**. In the XML content below there is content in the core submission area. If someone could kindly help me with this issue I would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php
        $post_string = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:roof="http://www.energystar.gov/schema/Roof_Products_2_x/" xmlns:core="http://www.energystar.gov/schema/core/">
           <soapenv:Body>
              <roof:Roof_Products_submission>
                 <core_submission>
                    <core:Authentication_UserName>xx</core:Authentication_UserName>
                    <core:Authentication_Password>xx</core:Authentication_Password>
                    <core:Certification_Body_EPA_Issued_Organization_Id>xx</core:Certification_Body_EPA_Issued_Organization_Id>
                    <core:Is_Test_Submission>Yes</core:Is_Test_Submission>
                 </core_submission>
                 <roof:Roof_Products>
                    <core:core_product_data>
                       <core:ENERGY_STAR_Manufacturing_Partner>QPX Active Partner</core:ENERGY_STAR_Manufacturing_Partner>
                       <core:ENERGY_STAR_Manufacturing_Partner_s_EPA_issued_Organization_ID>xx</core:ENERGY_STAR_Manufacturing_Partner_s_EPA_issued_Organization_ID>
                       <core:Partner_Contact_Name_For_This_Model>Benny</core:Partner_Contact_Name_For_This_Model>
                       <core:Type_of_Transaction>Initial Certification</core:Type_of_Transaction>
                       <core:Reason_for_Transaction>Initial Certification: Model Meets ENERGY STAR Requirements</core:Reason_for_Transaction>
                       <core:Date_of_Transaction_Type>2010-12-31</core:Date_of_Transaction_Type>
                       <core:ENERGY_STAR_Model_Identifier>TestID2929</core:ENERGY_STAR_Model_Identifier>
                       <core:Certification_ID>TestCertID123</core:Certification_ID>
                       <core:Family_ID>TestFamID123</core:Family_ID>
                       <core:Model_Name>Model_Name1234</core:Model_Name>
                       <core:Model_Number>Model_Number33453</core:Model_Number>
                       <core:Brand_Name>Brand_Name1</core:Brand_Name>
                       <core:Tested_Model_Name>Tested_Model_Name1</core:Tested_Model_Name>
                       <core:Tested_Model_Number>Tested_Model_Number1</core:Tested_Model_Number>
                       <core:Additional_Models_Represented_by_Family_Series_or_DOE_Basic>
                          <core:Additional_Model_Name>test</core:Additional_Model_Name>
                          <core:Additional_Model_Number>12345</core:Additional_Model_Number>
                          <core:Additional_Identifying_Information>non</core:Additional_Identifying_Information>
                       </core:Additional_Models_Represented_by_Family_Series_or_DOE_Basic>
                       <core:Is_the_Partner_Listed_the_Original_Equipment_Manufacturer_OEM>Yes</core:Is_the_Partner_Listed_the_Original_Equipment_Manufacturer_OEM>
                       <core:If_the_Partner_is_Not_the_Original_Equipment_Manufacturer_Who_is>test</core:If_the_Partner_is_Not_the_Original_Equipment_Manufacturer_Who_is>
                       <core:Currently_Available_on_Market>Yes</core:Currently_Available_on_Market>
                       <core:Date_Available_On_Market>2010-12-31</core:Date_Available_On_Market>
                       <core:Date_Tested>2010-12-31</core:Date_Tested>
                       <core:Date_CB_Notified_Partner_of_Model_Qualification>2010-12-31</core:Date_CB_Notified_Partner_of_Model_Qualification>
                       <core:Certification_Body_Contact_Name_for_This_Model>QPX Certification Body 1</core:Certification_Body_Contact_Name_for_This_Model>
                       <core:Laboratory>
                          <core:Laboratory_EPA_issued_Organization_ID>1114629</core:Laboratory_EPA_issued_Organization_ID>
                          <core:Laboratory_Contact_for_This_Model>QPX Laboratory Test</core:Laboratory_Contact_for_This_Model>
                       </core:Laboratory>
                       <core:To_What_Major_Markets_is_This_Model_Sold>United States</core:To_What_Major_Markets_is_This_Model_Sold>
                       <core:Notes>notes on the product</core:Notes>
                    </core:core_product_data>
                    <roof:ENERGY_STAR_Specification_Version>2.2</roof:ENERGY_STAR_Specification_Version>
                    <roof:Product_Type>Single-Ply</roof:Product_Type>
                    <roof:Measured_Initial_Solar_Reflectance>0.25</roof:Measured_Initial_Solar_Reflectance>
                    <roof:Reported_Initial_Solar_Reflectance>0.26</roof:Reported_Initial_Solar_Reflectance>
                    <roof:Initial_Solar_Reflectance_Test_Method>ASTM E903-96</roof:Initial_Solar_Reflectance_Test_Method>
                    <roof:Measured_Solar_Reflectance_After_Three_Years>0.15</roof:Measured_Solar_Reflectance_After_Three_Years>
                    <roof:Reported_Reflectance_After_Three_Years>0.16</roof:Reported_Reflectance_After_Three_Years>
                    <roof:Solar_Reflectance_After_Three_Years_Test_Method>ASTM C1549-09</roof:Solar_Reflectance_After_Three_Years_Test_Method>
                    <roof:Measured_Initial_Emissivity>0.01</roof:Measured_Initial_Emissivity>
                    <roof:Reported_Initial_Emissivity>0.02</roof:Reported_Initial_Emissivity>
                    <roof:Initial_Emissivity_Test_Method_Used>ASTM E408-71(1996) e1</roof:Initial_Emissivity_Test_Method_Used>
                    <roof:Low_Slope>Yes</roof:Low_Slope>
                    <roof:Steep_Slope>Yes</roof:Steep_Slope>
                    <roof:Roof_Cleaned_Prior_to_Third_Year_Test>No</roof:Roof_Cleaned_Prior_to_Third_Year_Test>
                    <roof:Warranty_Period>abcdefg</roof:Warranty_Period>
                 </roof:Roof_Products>
              </roof:Roof_Products_submission>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>';

        $url = "https://esws.energystar.gov:443/DataServices/servlet/webservices?ver=1.1";

        $client = new SoapClient($url,
                                array(
                                'trace' => 1,
                                'exceptions' => 1,
                                'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                                'encoding' => 'utf-8',
                                'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
                                )
         );

        $xmlvar = new SoapVar(
                     '<ns1:xmlDocument>'.$post_string.'</ns1:xmlDocument>',
                     XSD_ANYXML
         );

        try 
        {
            $params->post_string = (object)$xmlvar;
            $save_result = $client->Submit_Roof_Products_2_x($params);
            echo "<pre>\n\n";
            echo "Result1 :\n";
            var_dump($save_result);
            echo "</pre>";
        } 
        catch (SoapFault $e)
        {
            echo "SOAP Fault: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />\n";
        }

        echo "<pre>\n\n";
        echo "Request2 :\n";
        echo htmlspecialchars($soap->__getLastRequest())."\n";
        echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the core_submission property needs to be outside of the Roof_products_submission tag.  See here for a good example of how to implement:

http://www.energystar.gov/ia/partners/third_party_certification/downloads/sample_Roof_Products_2_x.xml

Hope that helps.